# Laravel Eloquent on fixtures club data

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to return a list of fixtures that have a team associated to them. The home team field in the fixtures table references the id on the team table and the same for the away team field:

```
teams
-------
id (int, primary)
name (varchar[255])

fixtures
-------
id (int, primary)
hometeam (int - references `id` on `teams`)
awayteam (int - references `id` on `teams`)
date (datetime)
```

I have a fixtures and team model seperately, at the moment I am only able to return the team id in the fixtures table and not the name associated to it from the team table. I believe this is because the magic models look for the same name as the field name, i.e. team instead of hometeam or awayteam.

Is there anyway I can get this to wor with eloquent or does it need an old fashioned join?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the models?

Answer (score 0):

At first, Eloquent search the key with the structured name. If your foreign key is different or parent model key isn't `id`, you can define the fields in relation.

Ref: [One To Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

```
/**
 * Get the team that owns the fixture.
 */
public function team()
{
    // hometeam: foreign_key
    // id: parent model primary key
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'hometeam', 'id');
}
```